# How to use ajax upload to improve my photo gallery?

Tags: jquery, photo-gallery

I am trying for days to make a photo gallery for my website ( I am a photographer), but when I put the photos ( one has 7-8 mb, 4300x3000), they load very slow. I searched on web what should I do, and I found something about ajax upload ( that Facebook is using the same thing , ajax). Actually, my gallery is very look alike to the FB photogallery, but without comments and that stuff. I need only the small thumbnails of the photos, and the effect that when you click the thumbnail your photo get to its normal dimension. I created a photo gallery like that , the only problem is the loading time, it almost crashes my computer, and I do not have time to manually resize every single photo. So, what should I know about this ajax uploading? How can I call a function that automatically resize my photo, like the Facebook do? This is how I far I got with my photo-gallery ( I put some webphotos for examples) http://jsfiddle.net/EChhQ/4/

HTML

```
<a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_CWcsH3xUmrE/TOWrqLVp--I/AAAAAAAAAG0/hN0hBxYVyTo/s1600/Poze%252520Roz%252520Dragalase.jpg"><img  id="imgredus" src="http://1.bp.blogspot.com/_CWcsH3xUmrE/TOWrqLVp--I/AAAAAAAAAG0/hN0hBxYVyTo/s1600/Poze%252520Roz%252520Dragalase.jpg" alt="" /></a>
                        <a class="fancybox-thumbs" data-fancybox-group="thumb" href="http://www.zega.ro/imagini/produse/mici/pulover-carina-portocaliu__azz53218_50_extra.jpg"><img id="imgredus" src="http://www.zega.ro/imagini/produse/mici/pulover-carina-portocaliu__azz53218_50_extra.jpg" alt="" /></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could implement your image resizing function as follows:

```
var max_w = 600; // set the image maximum width
var max_h = 300; // set the image maximum height
$("img").each(function(i) { // match all img elements
    var this_w = $(this).height();
    var this_h = $(this).width();
    // check which side of the image needs to be kept to the maximum 
    if (this_w/this_h < max_w/max_h) {
        var h = max_h;
        var w = Math.ceil(max_h/this_h * this_w);
    } else { // calculate proportionally
        var w = max_w;
        var h = Math.ceil(max_w/this_w * this_h);
    }
    // assign new height and width values using CSS
    $(this).css({ height: h, width: w });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i think your looking for something like this http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyPhoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/#prettyPhoto